# Recruiter said that form had been sent via email, but I still have not received it?

Tags: email

A recruiter called me and mentioned that she will be sending me a form in the next couple of minutes which had to be filled out ASAP.

However, I have been waiting a while and still have not received the email.
My question is:

> How do I politely ask a recruiter to send an email, which she said had been sent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You call back and say "The promised email didn't get here. Let me make sure you have my correct address / give you another address to try. And if you can tell me your email address, I can check my spam filters and make sure that won't get list there."

Exactly the same as for any other important email.

Answer (score 3):

If she said it was urgent and you didn't receive it in reasonable time, send her an email yourself or call her, asking if she could send it again.

The key thing is not to sound as if you are blaming the recruiter for forgetting to send it or emailing it to the wrong address. You can go along the lines of "Hi, I haven't received that form you asked me to fill up, maybe it got lost along the route. Can you re-send it, please?"

Don't over-think it. Also make sure you allow for enough time before asking, email sometimes takes a while to arrive.

Answer (score 3):

First check your mailbox in the spam folder.

If it is not in the spam folder, send an email so she can reply directly, so there will be no mistake in writing the email address. Follow up with an immediate phone call to clarify the situation "It seems the email didn't arrive, I sent you an email. Can you confirm you received it. Great. Please reply with the necessary form attached, and I will fill it out ASAP."

Don't stress about this. Remember that recruiters tend to be paid when someone gets hired, so she has just as much incentive to ensure you receive the form.